# How to make a button work like a html a tag with href

Tags: reactjs

I have the functional component below which I want to use
to download an excel file stored on the server to my computer.
When I use the html a tag with href, everthing works. Now I decided to change
this to a button.

How do I call my download function here to download my excel file?

Do I need to dispatch this?

```
        const MyfirstTest = () => {

          const download = () => {
            '/api/tester1/tester3'
          }

          return (
            <div> 
              <Button
                  variant={'primary'}
                  type={'button'}
                  squared={false}
                  uppercase={true}
                  className={classes.btn}
                  onClick={download}
                >
                  <IconButton icon={'download'} />
                  Download File
                </Button>

              </div>
          )
        }

        export default MyfirstTest
```

Comment: try using `window.open('url')` in the `download` function body. should work I think

Comment: It works but reloading the entire page which I don't  like. I don't want the page to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
      const download = () => {
      const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = '/api/tester1/tester3'
        link.setAttribute('download','fileName')
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        document.body.removeChild(link)
      }
```

You can achieve by creating an `Link` element and click on it.

Comment: The document has a name already. What is the importance of using filename? The user does not know the file name.

Comment: `download` is a boolean attribute, that is, in HTML, no value is required to use it. You can change to anything as long is `true` value. Eg:
`link.setAttribute('download','download')`